# solving a Diophantine like equation

Tags: diophantine-equations

In my project, I modeled my problem to a mathematical equation like below

A*X + B*Y + C*Z + D*K = 160

X, Y, Z, K ∈ [8, 40, 48, 80, 88, 120]

A, B, C, D are coefficients

The goal is to find the combination of (X, Y, Z, K) with their corresponding coefficient values. Is there any way to solve this problem ?

----------edit----------

All coefficients A, B, C, D > 0.
The goal is to find X an A, Y and B, Z and C, K and D.
The difference is that X, Y, Z, K are from the set [8, 40, 48, 80, 88, 120], and the A, B, C, D can be any value greater than zero.

Comment: Do you know the value of A,B,C,D ? Are there any other constraints (for example, positive integers) ?

Comment: we can intuitively set a limit for coefficients. For example, if you set the values of X, Y, Z, K to 8, then all the coefficients must be 5. So, intuitively, the coefficients should not be around 5

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(form of the problem changed so I'm editing this)

Since the coefficients can repeat, we're actually solving the problem
$$8a+40b+48c+80d+88e+120f=160$$
where each of $a,\ldots,f$ is greater than or equal to zero. Since $8+40+48+80>160$, at most three of the variables will be non-zero.

We also need to be able to write four non-zero terms, so $a+b+c+d+e+f\ge 4$.

A helpful first step is to divide by $8$, giving

$$a+5b+6c+10d+11e+15f=20$$

Two observations: we're really looking at
$$5b+6c+10d+11e+15f\le 20$$
since $a$ can be any non-negative integer.

Secondly, at most one of $\{d,e,f\}$ is greater than zero (and none of them can be greater than $1$).

These two points reduce the problem to a manageable one; there are essentially four cases corresponding to
$$(d,e,f) \in \{(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,1,0),(1,0,0)\}$$

These can either be done by hand or coded (I found $18$ solutions to this).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I did not say that X, Y, Z and K should not be equal.
one case is X = Y = Z = K = 40 -> so, all the coefficients will be 1. This is one possible result

Comment: OK, that was not clear from your question. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Is there a difference then between the solutions $2\cdot 8+4\cdot 8+6\cdot 8+8\cdot 8$ and $4\cdot 8+6\cdot 8+8\cdot 8+2\cdot 8$ ?

Comment: No. there is absolutely no difference

Comment: I understood your approach for solving the problem. But there is a strict constraint in the problem. The equation must have 4 elements which are X, Y, Z and K. it should be four elements. not more not less. 

of course we can satisfy the equation by below valuse:
X = 0
Y = 40   -> B = 1
Z = 0     
K = 120  -> D = 1
but X and Z must not be zero.

Comment: As long as $a+b+c+d+e+f\ge 4$, that constraint can be satisfied.

Comment: Is it clear now how solving the problem in my answer gives you the solutions to your original question? eg $(a,b,c,d,e,f) = (4,2,1,0,0,0)$ can give you the solutions $$4\cdot 8 + 1\cdot 40 + 1\cdot 40 + 1\cdot 48 = 160$$ or $$3\cdot 8 + 1\cdot 8 + 2\cdot 40 + 1\cdot 48 = 160$$

Comment: Yes. got it. Many thanks for your help